# How to upgrade via msi

Tags: installation, windows-installer, upgrade

I want to upgrade my product via msi setup. 
The Upgrade Code of both msi remains the same because it's the same product family. Even if I change Version/Product Code of the msi for updating it just tells me the product is already installed or asks me to repair it. it doesn't ever provide an update option that replaces the current installation.

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 Pro to generate the msi setup

Comment: What tool are you using to generate your MSI? Visual studio? WiX? Something else?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you change the `Version` property in your Setup project, Visual Studio should prompt you to also change the `ProductCode`. You must do this. Then, you must also set the `RemovePreviousVersion` property to true. Make sure the `UpgradeCode` stays the same.

This is probably the easiest way and, from reading your question, what you are looking for. Note that this is more of an uninstall, then reinstall, than an "upgrade" per se.

Comment: -1 Both are called 'upgrades'. MSI rules define a Major Upgrade as a uninstall/reinstall, with a change in ProductCode under the same family of UpgradeCodes. A Minor Ugrade changes only those Components that are different between the two verisons.

Comment: @DSims: Yes, I'm familiar with the MSI definitions and the inherent semantic ambiguity. Thanks for pointing this out. I only mentioned the uninstall/reinstall because I thought it might prevent some confusion. Many are bitten by this behavior when creating their initial installers. Although it is called an upgrade, that language does not conform to the way most non-installer people understand the term. As far as the OS is concerned, it is an entirely new product.

Comment: @Dave: sorry to be pedantic. Semantic precision is unfortunately crucial with MSI/Windows installer. It is an inherently fragile domain, the way MS structured it, and specific words have specific technical and business consequences.

Comment: It doesn't work in my case (VS 2010). I checked on Internet and found: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/1bf05cb7-9afb-42ba-9f19-4b68985ead23/ saying that you need to change the major version number but it doesn't work either. Any idea if I am missing something here?

Comment: Following up my previous issue with these instructions: If you are using .NET don't forget to increase the AssemblyVersion and AssemblyFileVersion. From Kimmo K via: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformssetup/thread/9ce5da29-3f37-4e7f-a548-1cbeb4a3e0a3