# Upgrade the installed program in computer c# windows application

Tags: c#, winforms

I made an application with version 1.0.0 and it installed in my computer (because I made a setup for it), but I already changed some code in it (and this version is 1.0.2). So, how do I make the application on my computer that has version 1.0.0 up to date to 1.0.2? What do I need to do in order to have my application in my computer or other computer that has version 1.0.0 to version 1.0.2?

I used MSI.

Comment: You could take a look at ClickOnce. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Check this post: [How to upgrade via msi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028425/how-to-upgrade-via-msi).

Additionality I recommend that you also check the [WiX Toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/) for creating Windows installers - it alows making almost everything

Answer (score 1):

There are two type of upgrade you can do,

`Upgrading the whole application`

When I say upgrading the whole application, existing application will be uninstalled and new msi will be installed with new changes, You can easily handle this with MSI.

1. Change the `version number` of the new MSI (default version is 1.0.0)
2. When you change the version VS will prompt a message whether to change the product code. select yes
3. Make sure `RemovePreviousVersion` property is set to true.
4. Also make sure `UpgradeCode` of old msi and new msi are same.

When you install new msi with above settings it will first remove any older application installed and then installed itself.

`Upgrading part of application`

When i say upgrading part of the application it could be a dll change or any other resource change. These kind of upgradings can not be handled through MSI(*Unless you write your own upgrade manager module*). But luckily Microsoft has an elegent technology to handle these type of upgrades it's called [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx).

> ClickOnce applications can be self-updating; they can check for newer
>   versions as they become available and automatically replace any
>   updated files. The developer can specify the update behavior; a
>   network administrator can also control update strategies, for example,
>   marking an update as mandatory. Updates can also be rolled back to an
>   earlier version by the end user or by an administrator