# Building MSI Project and Overwriting with Newer Version

Tags: wpf, windows-installer

I have a WPF application that I am building an MSI file off of. The project is a multiple of C# projects in one solution. My issue is that I am trying to overwrite an older project with a newer one by just running the msi file and not uninstalling the project. I have been able to run the new msi file without issue but some of the dlls are not being overwritten with the new ones? Any help how to configure the projects

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to upgrade via msi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028425/how-to-upgrade-via-msi)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overwriting Previous MSI File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23479960/overwriting-previous-msi-file)

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a duplicate post, see my comments to your earlier post. Short answers: you shouldn't really be doing updates this way, not because that's my opinion but because you will run into problems if you just keep doing this. Increment the file versions of any files you wish to be replaced.