# Product Version vs Assembly Verison

Tags: winforms, windows-installer, versioning, assemblyversions

I am having a winform application and a visual studio installer set up project with the project output set to this winform application.

This winform gets invoked from a website as an msi installer which saves the values in the registry for invocation of the winform app the next time as a uri protocol scheme.

Now from the web I want to check 2 things:

1.) Is this application already installed on the client machine?

For this I can put a registry checking code to check for application installed or not

```
string regKey = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
using (Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(regKey))
{
    if (key.GetSubKeyNames().Any(keyName => key.OpenSubKey(keyName).GetValue("DisplayName") == "My App's Display Name"))
        Console.WriteLine("Already installed...");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Start installing...");
}
```

2.) What is the version of the application installed.

For the version, the registry values as described in point 1 also gives other parameters like "DisplayVersion" and "version, VersionMajor and VersionMinor".

So for the version what is the best way to update the assembly version of the winform application. Should I change the AssemblyInfo class of the winform app or should I change the version in the set up project properties?.

Set up project property:
[image]

Also in the registry I get following dword values of versions, how to decode these hexadecimal values to get the version number?.

[image]

Comment: Anyone any help?. These days nobody answers any questions of mine?. Is my account not eligible or blocked or listed, so it should not get answers?. Other many generic questions get answered on stackoverflow, so my question seems genuine or there are no technical advisors left here?

Comment: Why don't you just use the resultant MSI to update the assembly by upgrading the previously installed MSI?  As such you shouldn't really require any logic to check for existing versions from a code perspective. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028425/how-to-upgrade-via-msi